# Writing .dds Images in Java

Tags: java, image

Currently, I am loading and editing a .dds Image using the [java-dds plugin](http://code.google.com/p/java-dds/).
After editing the Image I'd like to save it as a .dds again, but i only found plugins capable of reading such images, not writing.

So do you know any Java libraries capable of reading AND writing .dds files?